# Building CNN, Need More Images

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm building a custom Convolutional Neural Network for image recognition.  I'm running into the issue of only having around 100 images or so to train and test on.  From my research and model results, this is not enough.

Does anyone who of a service for hire to have someone search web/research and build up images based on certain criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you using `Keras` and employing its pre-trained models. Because of low number of data-set, you should use [transfer learning](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiPoa-KzofYAhUDaVAKHXhbDkAQFggpMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FTransfer_learning&usg=AOvVaw2HhdpOpHnaIlHbqcB21o43). There are lots of researches about that like [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiPoa-KzofYAhUDaVAKHXhbDkAQFghJMAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcs231n.github.io%2Ftransfer-learning%2F&usg=AOvVaw3meugAV_bCpOZhjgZv3eRW). Based on the data that you have, you should choose a model which is appropriate for your task and have been trained for tasks which are like yours, and then use it. I guess *ResNet* and *GoogleNet* already have been trained on *ImageNet* data set and are in the `Keras`. You have to freeze the weights of the convolution and dense layers. You should change the soft-max layer with your own. In this kind of learning, the pre-trained model has already the ability to find features. You are just supposed to let it learn how to classify your data.

Answer (score 2):

You should apply data augmentation to generate more data. Check [this](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) and [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/image-augmentation-deep-learning-keras/)